# generate new column on multiindex dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have this dataframe that I achieved with Pivot

```
df.pivot_table(index=('country','city'), columns="year", values="values",\
aggfunc=np.sum)

               year     2000    2018
country        city
 USA         W, D.C       5       10
                NYC      11       20 

 X            alpha       5        1
               beta       0        2
```

I want to create a new column that will have the difference of the values in the columns 2000 and 2018
Something like this:

```
               year     2000    2018    Diff 
country        city
 USA         W, D.C       5       10      -5
                NYC      11       20      -9

 X            alpha       5        1       4
               beta       0        2      -2
```

However, I am not able to access these columns and perform any operation!

Answer (score 0):

You can take difference by following code:

```
df.columns = ['2000', '2018']
df['Diff'] = df['2000'] - df['2018']
```